# How to delete a file from WordPress plugin folder

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a WordPress plugin. It uses a cached xml file in the plugin folder /cache/feed.xml. Now I want to make it possible for the admin to delete this file from the plugins option page. Button or text link. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

On form submit or AJAX call, whichever you like more

**PHP**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_unique_enqueue_assets');
add_action('wp_ajax_my_cache_removal', 'my_cache_removal_ajax_handler');

function my_unique_enqueue_assets()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('my_script', plugins_url('/my_script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), false, true);
    wp_localize_script('my_script', 'my_script_ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}

function my_cache_removal_ajax_handler()
{
    if(file_exists (plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'cache/feed.xml'))
    {
        unlink(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'cache/feed.xml')
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) 
{
    $('#clear_mah_cache').click(function()
    {
        $.ajax({type: "post", dataType: "json", url: my_script_ajax_object.ajax_url, data: {action: 'my_cache_removal'}}).done(function (e)
        {
            alert('You cache is kaput now');
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="spr_reset_votes">Clear dat cache</button>
```

Comment: Hi Igor. Thanks! Could you give me a Ajax example with this code?

Comment: Thanks Igor! How do I call it? Could you give me an example with al button or txt link? I'm very thankfull

Comment: @Gerard check my answer again.